# How to mock Smart GWT ListGrid

Tags: gwt, mocking, smartgwt

Has any one been able to mock Smart GWT ListGrid, using for example PowerMock? If so, can you share an example, please.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to do it. Use DataBoundComponent interface, or another interface ListGrid implements that you want to access and mock that instead.